# Xaml Xamarin Ошибка условий

Tags: xaml, xamarin, условия

```
            <Label>
            <Label.Style>
                <Style TargetType="Label">
                    <Setter Property="Text" Value="Condition is true" />
                    <Style.Triggers>
                        <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Swi}" Value="False">
                            <Setter Property="Text" Value="Condition is true" />
                        </DataTrigger>
                    </Style.Triggers>
                </Style>
            </Label.Style>
        </Label>
выдает ошибку:
```

Серьезность Код Описание    Проект  Файл    Строка  Состояние подавления
Ошибка  XHR0012 Член "Text" не распознан или недоступен.    ZatemtkiEnd C:\Users\valav\source\repos\ZatemtkiEnd\ZatemtkiEnd\ZatemtkiEnd\ZametkiAdd.xaml 37